# How to make an array of functions, and how to call it

Tags: solidity, remix

this:

```
    mapping(uint => function()) funcMap;
```

doesn't give any error in Remix.

But I don't know how to call it:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;
contract b {
    mapping(uint => function()) funcMap;
    function g() public view {
        uint x=0;
    }
    function update() public {
        funcMap[1] = g();
    }
```

this line

```
        funcMap[1] = g();
```

gives this error:

```
browser/Playground.sol:14:22: TypeError: Type tuple() is not implicitly convertible to expected type function ().
    funcMap[1] = g();
                 ^-^
```

Answer (score 3):

> Remove parentheses of g function from `funcMap[1] = g();` and set
>   `funcMap[1] = g;`.

look this code run without error:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;
contract b {
    mapping(uint => function()) funcMap;

    function g() public pure {
        uint x=0;
    }

    function update() public {
        funcMap[1] = g;
    }

}
```

Comment: It did solve the problem, thanks. But now when I try to return a uint in g(), it shows an error.
It says:
(line of funcMap[1] = g;):(error points to '['): TypeError: Type function () view returns (uint256) is not implicitly convertible to expected type function ().

Comment: If your function returning uint256 value then your mapping should be like this `mapping(uint => uint256) funcMap;` and you assign it like `funcMap[1] = g();`

Comment: @Ornataweaver Try `mapping(uint => function() returns (uint)) funcMap;` and `function g() public pure returns (uint) { return 33; }`.